# Keep jquery code active

Tags: jquery

I have this code in my AJAX success function:

```
$('#grid tr').click(function () {

                    $(this).addClass('select');
                    $('#grid tr').not(this).removeClass('select');

                    var ID = $('.select td').first().text();
                    $("#edit").attr("href", "/Alumnoes/Edit/" + ID);
```

What it does is 1) Highlight last clicked row. 2) Generate an edit href for the selected id.

I'm using webgrid for the table and when I click the headers to sort whichever column I lose the above functionality. How can I reorganize / relocate this code so it's responsive regardless of the sorting refresh?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands now I have gone with the following solution, not my first pick but works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function clicker() {
    $('#grid tr').click(function () {

        $(this).addClass('select');
        $('#grid tr').not(this).removeClass('select');

        var ID = $('.select td').first().text();
        $("#edit").attr("href", "/Alumnoes/Edit/" + ID);
    });
}
setInterval(function () { clicker() }, 250);
</script>
```

EDIT:

I've solved the problem with the following:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, canSort: true, rowsPerPage: 5, ajaxUpdateCallback: "clicker", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
```

Using the ajaxUpdateCallback option to fire clicker() function every time the webgrid updates.